# Random walk on $\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z$ converges to uniform distribution

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

> Let $(X_t)_t$ be the standard continuous time random walk on $\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z$ with $X(0)=[0]$ almost surely, then I want to show that for $t \rightarrow \infty$, $\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} P(X(t)=[n]\mid X(0)=[0])= \frac{1}{m}$ for any $[n] \in Z/mZ.$

More precisely the random walk is defined in such a way that the rate of going from $[n]$ to $[n+1]$ is 1 and also the rate of going from $[n]$ to $[n-1].$
By rate I mean the number $$\left.\frac{d}{dt}P(X(t)=[n+1]\mid X(0)=[n])\right|_{t=0}.$$

The problem here is that $m$ is not fixed, so we cannot explicitly constuct the transition probabilities, I guess. Nevertheless, I guess that the simple structure of the random walk enables us to get this result still somehow.

Comment: Why is $ m $ not fixed?

Comment: @user226970 in the sense that I would like to have an answer for arbitrary $m.$ So I want to show this for any $m \in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: I see. Why can't you write down the markov matrix, and check that the uniform distribution is the stationary distribution.

Comment: @user226970 it is a continuous-time markov chain.

Comment: no I mean the discrete set Z/mZ, the continuity is in time not in the walk.

Comment: it would still converge to the uniform distribution with $(X_n)$ being a Markov process

Comment: There is a transition matrix for continuous time as well, see for example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous-time_Markov_chain#Stationary_distribution

Comment: @user226970 yeah, but if $m$ is not fixed you cannot write down the answer so easily.

Comment: @user1952009 how do you show this? I doubt this result, as in the discrete case you would have some periodicitiy issues if $m$ is even for instance.

Comment: First the OP should be complimented for their healthy skepticism regarding handwavy approaches. Second, generally speaking, a useful tool to study random walks on discrete circles is *discrete Fourier analysis*. Here, this amounts to considering the functions $$g_z(t)=E(z^{X(t)}),$$ for every nonnegative real number $t$ and every $z$ in $Z$ the set of $m$th roots of unity. A crucial fact is that $X(t)$ converges to the uniform distribution if and only if $$g_z(t)\to0$$ for every  $z\ne1$ in $Z$ (this is because each $P(X(t)=k)$ is a fixed linear combination of the values $g_z(t)$). ...

Comment: ... Now, the dynamics of the process translates as $$g_z'(t)=a(z)\cdot g_z(t),\qquad a(z)=\tfrac12(z+z^{-1})-1,$$ hence $$g_z(t)=g_z(0)\cdot e^{a(z)t},$$ and the result holds if and only if $\Re a(z)<0$ for every $z\ne1$ in $Z$. But such $z$ are $z=e^{i\theta}$ with $|\theta|\leqslant\pi$ and $\theta\ne0$ hence $a(z)=\cos\theta-1$ and the proof is complete.

Comment: *Correction: The way you define the random walk, it moves at rate $2$, not $1$ (I read your post too quickly, at first), hence each $a(z)$ above should be replaced by $2a(z)$, with no consequence on the final result.

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches. One way is to use the procedure for continuous-time markov chain analysis by finding an embedded markov chain which operates in discrete time. You can read [details here](http://dept.stat.lsa.umich.edu/~ionides/620/notes/cts_time_markov_chains.pdf). In this case, the embedded chain is simply $X_n$ which is a simple random walk on $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$. This is a finite state space, and $X_n$ is aperiodic for $m$ odd, where it has a unique stationary distribution. You can show this stationary distribution $\pi$ is $\pi_t=1/m$ in a number of ways. The first is to write down the transition matrix $P$ for $X_n$, and verify that the above stationary distribution satisfies $\pi P=\pi$, and then invoke uniqueness. An easier way is to notice that $X_n$'s distribution is cyclically invariant under rotations of $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ which means that $\pi$ must have equal probability 
for all states.

To carry this over to a continuous time markov chain, you need the following result which connects to the embedded markov chain:

$$\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}P(X_t = j | X_0=i) = \frac{\pi_j/v_j}{\sum_k \pi_k/v_k},$$

where $v_k$ are the transition rates for your continuous time chain, all of which are $1$.

When $m$ is even $X_n$ is periodic. Despite this $X(t)$ will still have a stationary distribution, primarily because periodicity does not exist in continuous time. To see this you can use the fact that if a probability vector $\pi$ satisfies the local balance equations (see page 253 of [this](http://www.mast.queensu.ca/~stat455/lecturenotes/set5.pdf)):

$$\pi_iq_{ij}=\pi_jq_{ji},$$

where $q_{ij}$ are transition rates, then $\pi$ must be a stationary distribution of $P(t)$. You can double check $\pi_i=1/m$ satisfies the above equations with $q_{ij}=1$ for $|i-j|=1$ and 0 otherwise. Note that not all stationary distributions satisfy local balance equations.

This reasoning uses the fact that if $\pi$ is the stationary distribution of a continuous time Markov chain, it is unique.

Comment: why is it aperiodic? It $m$ is even and the chain starts in zero, then we are at all even points $n$ with our $X_n$ in an even state and at all odd points $n$ in an odd state?

Comment: @The You are in continuous time, so aperiodicity is not an issue at all - there is a positive probability to end up in any state in $\epsilon$ time.

Comment: @A.S. well, maybe this is not an issue, but I only expressed my concern about the reasoning in this answer. Do you know how to show this?

Comment: @TheHomeworker: see edit.

Comment: @AlexR. the problem is that all this is far away from a rigorous proof... . Do you think you can turn all this into a consistent argument? So without assuming further knowledge, do you think you can show the convergence to the uniform distribution?

Comment: @TheHomeworker: with local balance equations, the proof is one line. Are you asking to derive the proof that local balance equations imply $\pi$ is stationary? If yes, refer to the second link above.

Comment: @AlexR. the main issue is that I cannot show that convergence of the discrete time chain implies convergence of the continuous-time chain.

Comment: Indeed the *détour* by the discrete case introduces unnecessary complications. Better to attack the continuous case head on, with some suitable tools.